# How to mutate static ref usize?

Tags: rust, thread-safety, global-variables, lazy-static

```rust
lazy_static! {
  static ref MY_GLOBAL: Mutex<usize> = Mutex::new(100);
}
```

```rust
MY_GLOBAL.lock().unwrap() += 1;
```

This code gives me these errors:

```
cannot use `+=` on type `MutexGuard<'_, usize>`
```

```
cannot assign to this expression
```

How do I mutate `MY_GLOBAL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code needs just one `*`:

```rust
*MY_GLOBAL.lock().unwrap() += 1;
```

The result of `MY_GLOBAL.lock().unwrap()` is a `MutexGuard<'_, usize>`, as the compiler noted, which *dereferences to* a `usize`, so to modify the containing usize you need a dereference `*`.

Rust often automatically inserts referencing and dereferencing when needed (particularly for method calls) but for an assignment you must explicitly dereference so that the left side is exactly the `usize` you intend to replace.